# How to set body for WebOperationContext.OutgoingWebResponseContext

Tags: .net, response

I am trying to set body for `WebOperationContext.OutgoingResponse` which is `OutgoingWebResponseContext` but the only thing I found is `OutgoingResponse.StatusCode` and `OutgoingResponse.StatusDescription`, but I would like to return a string in the body. However I can't find any way to do it.

Comment: @wp78de No, the solution was to return `Task<string>` and set in the contract that the endpoint returns `JSON`.

Comment: Cool. Maybe you want to add your own answer.